# in QT how to make .cpp and .h files from .ui file?

Tags: qt

Used to be able to use uic to make them.

From windows command line, what is command to generate .cpp and .h files from a qt .ui file??

thats from the CMD.EXE command line, giving as input the .UI file and wanting .CPP AND .H

Comment: What did you try? Most build systems generate corresponding rules automatically.

Answer (score 0):

That's what qmake would generate:
`uic somefile.ui -o ui_somefile.h`